# Use Event bindind on a Angular 5 component with ngIf

Tags: angular, events

I'm scratching my head to make works this code :

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked *ngIf="datas" #charts [scheme]="colorScheme" [results]="datas" [gradient]="gradient" [xAxis]="showXAxis"
    [yAxis]="showYAxis" [legend]="showLegend" [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
    [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

The problem is that datas is asynchronous. So it need the * ngIf directive, to wait for datas to be fill. * ngIf removes the component from the DOM, so select event is never trigger.

Data are loads into the ngOninit() hooks.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadHisto();
}

/**
   * Load histogram with filter.
   */
  loadHisto() {
    const params = []
    params['search'] = [];
    params['search']['minDate'] = this.minDate;
    params['search']['maxDate'] = this.maxDate;
    params['search']['interval'] = this.interval;
    this.histoSubscription.add(this.elkService.findHisto(params).subscribe(datas => {
      this.datas = datas;
    }));
  }
```

Any Solutions? I already tried all solutions found on internal, but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set an initial value like this :

```
datas = [];
```